# How to receive Brain Tree payment_method_nonce without a form post back?

Tags: javascript, c#, braintree

I am new to Brain Tree. I want to accept payments on my web site using Brain Tree. On client side I use javascript and on the server side C#. I use their drop in form in order to collect card information. All the examples I saw on Brain Tree developer side instructs me to do a form submission in order to receive payment_method_nonce on the server. In my web site I handle interactions through callbacks in order to avoid full page refresh. They let me define a callback method in the setup for receiving payment_method_nonce, but is there a way to initiate call to brain tree server through their client side javascript api in order to request payment_method_nonce by avoiding form postback?

Answer (score -1):

I work as a developer for Braintree. There are [global configurations](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+dotnet/guides/client-sdk#global-setup) that can be used with the Drop-in integration to do this.

The `onPaymentMethodReceived` callback halts the form submission after the payment method is tokenized. You can use it to capture the payment method nonce and insert your own code to do what you want in place of the form submission.

Add the callback to your global setup like this:

```
braintree.setup(clientTokenFromServer, "dropin", {
    container: "checkout",
    onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj) {
        // Insert your code here to capture and use the payment method nonce
        // console.log(obj.nonce);
    }
});
```

[See more details about the `onPaymentMethodReceived` callback and the object it returns here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+dotnet/guides/client-sdk#payment-method-details). Hope that helps!

Comment: I already figured this out. The only problem is that you guys designed drop in controls to be more like in a stand alone page. It doesn't integrate well with a page that has more functionality. What I mean is that there might be other things that cause post back on the page which has nothing to do with payments, but this callback is called regardless and the drop in controls' inputs get validated.